# Field available only when a value from a Hierarchical Select is chosen

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am using the Hierarchical Select module to allow users to first select a continent and then a country. I wish to enable a field only when a user selects *North America* (first selection) and *USA* (second selection).

I hope someone could explain how I achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states). Quick tutorial: http://randyfay.com/states
Example: http://d7.drupalexamples.info/examples/form_example/states

Answer (score 0):

I created a module that implemented the node_validate function and from the values selected determined if child taxonomies existed when the form was submitted. If they did then obviously the user had not made a selection from the second drop down list.

This is the code I wrote.

```php
function mp_admin_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {     
    if ($form["#form_id"]=="jobs_node_form") {
        $loc = taxonomy_get_children( $node->field_tax_regions[und][0][tid]);     
        if ((count($loc)>0) && ($loc)) {
            form_set_error("field_tax_regions", t('Location region is required.')); 
        } 
    }
}
```